# Test file existence outside DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file inside DOCUMENT_ROOT where it checks for the existence of a file, maintenance.enable and serves maintenance.html if it is present:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # This portion checks for the presence of maintenance.enable to toggle
    # maintenance mode
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
    ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
    Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store"

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, it doesn't seem to work outside DOCUMENT_ROOT. For example, considering I have a folder structure like this:

```
document_root/
  .htaccess
  index.php
  maintenance.html
  maintenance.enable
  test/
     .htaccess
     index.php
     maintenance.enable
     maintenance.html
outside_document_root/
   .htaccess
   index.php
   maintenance.html
   maintenance.enable
```

The folder `outside_document_root` is defined as an alias in the conf file.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should not use `.htaccess` at all if you have access to configuration files as it slows down Apache. You could have all these settings inside the configuration file instead.

Configuration in `.htaccess` applies to the folder and it's sub-folders. You should have this `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block inside the `<virtualHost>` directive to apply it on the whole VirtualHost including the folder defined by an alias.

If you prefer use `.htaccess`anyway, you can replace the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` with the absolute filesystem path to the file.

Comment: Thanks but when I used the absolute system path, I'm getting a 404